# const in method is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I am currently studying OOJS and I am working on a simple system to practice knowledge. I have a class `Author`, a class `AuthorDAO`and `test`. In `AuthorDAO` check if has another same email registered and works fine. But, my `const hasAuthor` when called `typeof` I get: `undefined` and I don't understand the reason and because doesn't affect result of the test. Why `hasAuthor`returns `undefined`? What type should it return?

Class Author

```
import { mailFormat, isEmpty, isNull } from "../validate.js";

export default class Author {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setEmail(email);
    this._date = new Date();
  }

  setName(name) {
    if (isEmpty(name) || isNull(name))
      throw new Error(`the field needs to be filled`);
    this._name = name;
  }

  setEmail(email) {
    if (isEmpty(email) || !email.match(mailFormat))
      throw new Error(
        `the field needs to be filled`
      );
    this._email = email;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  get email() {
    return this._email;
  }
}
```

Class AuthorDAO

```
import Author from "../models/Author.js";

export default class AuthorDAO {
  constructor() {
    this._list = [];
  }

  findEmail(email) {
    const author = this._list.find((author) => author.email === email);
    if (author instanceof Author) {
      return author;
    }
  }

  add(author) {
    const hasAuthor = this.findEmail(author.email);
    if (hasAuthor) throw new Error(`email already registered`);

    this._list.push(author);
    console.log(typeof hasAuthor === "undefined");//true
  }
}
```

test

```
import Author from "../models/Author.js";
import AuthorDAO from "../dao/Author.js";

try {
  const authorDAO = new AuthorDAO();
  const author1 = new Author("Jack", "jack55@gmail.com");
  const author2 = new Author("jack", "jack55@gmail.com");
  authorDAO.add(author1);
  authorDAO.add(author2);
  console.log(`saved ${author1.name} ${author1.email}`);
  console.log(`saved ${author2.name} ${author2.email}`);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error " + error);
}
```

And in my method `findEmail` the condition needs `if`case author don't be `Author`?

Sorry for basic questions and sorry for my English poor.

Comment: This code looks very familiar. Did you post something similar a few days ago?

Comment: `findEmail()` only does `return author` when the author is found in the array. Otherwise it returns `undefined` by default.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, with your help, I understood the previous problem of my Author class, but now I can't understand why receiving undefined. Sorry to be a similar subject, but I just can't understand it. If it's wrong I can erase

Comment: What do you expect to receive instead of `undefined`?

Comment: You throw an error when you receive something other than `undefined`. So if you get to the `typeof` expression, it must be `undefined`.

Comment: You could just do `return author` in `findEmail`. `this._list.find()` returns the found object or `null`. There's no need to test `instanceof`.

Comment: I had an idea that it would be wrong to get undefined. When *You could just do return author in findEmail. this._list.find()* would be elminate method `add`?

Comment: If you don't want to get undefined you have to return something else. You could put `else { return null; }` in `findEmail`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because `findEmail()` doesn't return anything when the email isn't found. If a function ends without executing `return <something>`, it returns `undefined` by default. If you don't want to get that, you have to return something else.

```
  findEmail(email) {
    const author = this._list.find((author) => author.email === email);
    if (author instanceof Author) {
      return author;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

You could just return `author` instead, since it will always be either an `Author` instance or `null`.

```
  findEmail(email) {
    return this._list.find((author) => author.email === email);
  }
```

Comment: Barmar! Thank you very much. You had a great didactic!!